# How to hold MYSQL performance while large data file import using LOAD DATA INFILE?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, import, load-data-infile, large-data

I'm working with a large database (some tables 500000000+ rows) . Each day 3-10 millions rows should be replaced and each import is about 1 million rows (so 3-10 times a day with CRON) using LOAD DATA INFILE. 
The problem is, that while making such big file import, MySQL eats 80% of CPU and all common queries going from website became very slow or website performance falls down. 
Site is running under Amazon's EC2 Windows 2008 server. 
Does anyone know how to solve this problem within one EC2 instance (without splitting database)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty hack... What about splitting the source files into smaller loads, which are then cron'ned as a DB load operation, with a 5 minute break between each load? Managing 10 million records at a time will exhaust many server and DB resources, and hence the crash. Using loads of only 50-100K may not be too bad if you have a large server with lots of memory.

Answer (score 1):

distribution seems the way to go (that's how facebook does things)

not sure what is the rational for you not to do so, budget constraints?

other possible approaches

- **discard use of windows** - [limitation of windows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limits-windows.html)
- setup mysql replication
- during import via cron, prevent all query hit to master,and vice versus. once the import is completed (something like set two flag files, if master flag exist, use slave, if slave flag file exist, use master, both not exist, then both can be query)
- consider [partition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html)?
- discard all index (bear the consequence)

is much depend on your database usage, if not mission critical, do an offline import much suitable